# Issue in Adding Module dependency for OpenCv

Tags: android, android-studio, opencv, dependencies

I am trying to add Module Dependency for Open Cv.

For that I have downloaded latest OpenCv library from the below link :
https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-android/3.4.3/

Then, In Android Studio, I have done as below :

**File > New > Import Module**

In this way, I have imported a module/directory for OpenCv.

Now, I have to add Module Dependency for the added module.
To do so I am trying to do as below :

**File > Project Structure > Dependencies > + > Module Dependency**

But, It showing me: **Select at least one module**

What might be the issue?

Comment: you need to select java folder which will be inside the android-sdk folder in opencv folders

Comment: ya I have selected it by following reference from this link : https://android.jlelse.eu/a-beginners-guide-to-setting-up-opencv-android-library-on-android-studio-19794e220f3c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's Solved by editing build.gradle of Opencv as below :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        //applicationId "org.opencv"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}
```

Changed **apply plugin: 'com.android.library'** from **apply plugin: 'com.android.application'**

and

Commented below line :

**applicationId "org.opencv"**

Answer (score 0):

The issue can be resolved, If you are not able to add the dependency from the project structure while you can directly write it in the `build.gradle` of app.

Note: Do not rename the opencv folder while you were adding it as a module in your project.

In `build.gradle` of app write:

```
dependencies{
implementation project (':openCVLibrary347') // The name of my opencv module folder 
}
```